# There's some way to create a user-defined type modifier?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a lazy-c++ in order to do that I've got `Lazy<T>` that is a simple type alias for `std::function<T(void)>`. Now the code that I can write looks like this:

```
Lazy<int> first(Lazy<int> a, Lazy<int> b)
{
    return [a] { return a(); };
}
```

And adding the following macros:

```
#define lazy(T, name, ...) Lazy<T> name (__VA_ARGS__)
#define lazy_return(lazy_value) return [lazy_value] { return lazy_value(); }
```

First looks like this:

```
lazy(int, first, Lazy<int> a, Lazy<int> b)
{  
    lazy_return(a);
}
```

And the code that I want to have is:

```
lazy int first(lazy int a, lazy int b)
{  
    return a; // <- auto-deduced lazy_return because first was marked as lazy
}
```

Is there some way (preferably without external libraries) in that I can write the code as I want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some way (preferably without external libraries) in that I can write the code as I want to?

No. C++ simply doesn't have that level of grammatical flexibility.
And you can't use the macro system to get their either.

But, I think there's a deeper issue here. Your desired language has some pretty simple ambiguities. Consider `lazy int * a` is this a pointer to a lazy int, or a lazy pointer to int?

C++ templates obey a grammar that allow us avoid these kinds of ambiguity; the difference between these two cases is simple and obvious `Lazy<int*> a` vs `Lazy<int> *a`.